Why must bubble curve and dew curve meet at azeotropic point?
This question is based on a similar question here, but the answers there didn't address why bubble curve and dew curve must meet at azeotropic point.
I have come up with a almost complete qualitative reasoning for it, but i need some help.

It is simple.
If the liquid and vapor curves did not meet at the azeotropic composition, azeotrope vapor at given p would have different composition than liquid, therefore it would not be an azeotropic mixture.
As the same composition of both is the definition of an azeotropic mixture.

that simply rephrases the question, why does azeotropic point must lie at maxima/minima for dew/bubble curves?

It rather points out the case, if A is defined having property X, and if property Y is the direct consequence of the property X,  and then asking why A must have property Y.  // Azeotropes formally behave in the phase equilibrium context like if they were single volatile substances, Both vapor/liquid curves meat at single substances, because composition of their liquid and vapor phase is obviously the same.

There are three statements about azeotropes, Azeotrope and its vapor have the same composition, Bubble curve and dew curve meet at azeotropic point, and Maxima/Minima of bubble/dew curves must be an azeotropic point. Statement 1 and Statement 2 are equivalent, but i dont see how Statement 3 follows from the first two statements.

Here is my qualitative reasoning on why bubble curve and dew curve must meet at azeotropic point. I will not argue for this directly but state and justify statements leading upto why the curves must meet.
Basic definitions first:
For a specific composition of solution, Bubble Temperature is  the minimum temperature at which boiling starts, aka the temperature at which the first vapor bubble forms.
As the solution starts to boil, the first vapour bubble (usually) has different composition than the liquid solution. The vapour has a larger mole fraction of the more volatile component, compared to its mole fraction in liquid solution. Thus, as boling progresses, boiling point of the solution increases.
Dew Temperature, for a specific composition of solution, is the minimum temperature at which the solution boils off completely. Alternatively, it is also the maximum temperature at which vapor(of a specific composition) can condense into liquid, or upon cooling a vapor mixture, first dew starts to form at dew temperature.
Statement 1: Dew temperature is higher than Bubble Temperature.
Consider a liquid solution S, with composition (Xa, Xb) in a closed container. It exists in equilibrium with a vapour mixture V, with composition (Ya, Yb) over it. The container is maintained at a constant temperature T. Bubble temperature of vapour V, when condensed will be lower than that of the liquid solution S. This is because T is both the dew temperature for vapour V, and bubble temperature of liquid solution S, and so bubble temperature of vapour V must be smaller than T, thus smaller than the bubble temperature of liquid solution S. It is equivalent to saying, vapour collected over a liquid solution, when condensed will have a lower boiling point than the liquid solution itself, or, liquid mixture condensed from a vapour mixture has a lower dew point than the vapour mixture itself.
Statement 2: dew temperature of vapour = bubble temperature of solution
Statement 3: bubble temperature of Vapour < bubble temperature of liquid solution
Statement 4: dew temperature of Vapour < dew temperature of liquid solution
bubble curve and dew curve must meet at their maximas/minimas. This is equivalent to saying that at azeotropic point, composition of vapour and liquid solution is the same.
Case1: consider a minimum boiling point azeotrope solution S. The vapour collected over S, when condensed must have a lower (or equal) bubble point than S(statement3), but since S has minimum bubble temperature, bubble temperature of its vapour must be equal to bubble temperature of the solution, which will be equal to the dew temperature of vapor (statement 2). Thus dew curve and bubble curve will meet at minima for boiling point azeotrope.
A similar argument can be established for maximum boiling point azeotropes too.
I intuitively know that reasoning in case 1 should also imply that vapour and liquid must have the same composition but i couldn't phrase it more rigorously. My first instinct was to conclude that since vapour and liquid have same bubble temperature, they must have the same composition, but since bubble temperature is not a one to one function of mixture composition, i cannot say that without any further restriction. What possible restriction could i be missing?
